# How to add new plots of different scale to an existing histogram?

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

I have a Matlab figure with two histograms on it

[image],

created with `hist()` function. Now I want to add two plots in the same figure (bell distribution actually:

[image],

but they have different scale. I thought I could use plotyy, but I already have my first plot-scale on the figure. How can I add the second plot-scale?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, this is one way to do it:

```
%// example data
rng(0,'twister')
data = randn(1000,3);
x = linspace(-4,4,100);
y = 16 - x.^2;

%// generate two axes at same position
ax1 = axes;
ax2 = axes('Position', get(ax1, 'Position'),'Color','none');

%// move second axis to the right, remove x-ticks and labels
set(ax2,'YAxisLocation','right')
set(ax2,'XTick',[])

%// plot hist and line plot
hist(ax1,data); hold on
plot(ax2,x,y)

ylabel(ax1,'label of hist')
ylabel(ax2,'label of plot')
xlabel(ax1,'Hello World!')
```

[image]